# Compute NUM of days from UNION of time ranges (with DateTime::Span)

Tags: perl, datetime

I have a set of time ranges and need to get the Number of days from this set. I did it with `DateTime::Span` as follows:

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Span;

sub printHash {
    my $hash = shift;
    foreach my $key (keys %{$hash}) {
        print "$key: $hash->{$key}\n";
    }
}

$date1 = DateTime->new( year => 2002, month => 3, day => 11 );
$date2 = DateTime->new( year => 2002, month => 4, day => 12 );
$date3 = DateTime->new( year => 2003, month => 8, day => 26 );
$date4 = DateTime->new( year => 2003, month => 9, day => 15 );
$date5 = DateTime->new( year => 2004, month => 7, day => 6 );
$date6 = DateTime->new( year => 2004, month => 10, day => 15 );

$set1 = DateTime::Span->from_datetimes( start => $date1, end => $date2 );
$set2 = DateTime::Span->from_datetimes( start => $date3, end => $date4 );
$set3 = DateTime::Span->from_datetimes( start => $date5, end => $date6 );

$set123 = $set1->union( $set2, $set3 );

printHash(\%$set123);

#--------------------------------

set123:
set: [2002-03-11T00:00:00..2002-04-12T00:00:00],[2003-08-26T00:00:00..2003-09
T00:00:00],[2004-07-06T00:00:00..2004-10-15T00:00:00]
```

Is there a way to extract the Number of days in this `$set123`? Thanks a lot!

**Update:** I can do it with `delta_days` but it's actually I do need a UNION of the time ranges then find the Number of days within this UNION set. I find `DateTime::Span` works well to find the UNION but I just need to know how to extract the Number of days in it. Since I need a solution in a hurry, so please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're calling `union` incorrectly. It only takes one argument.

```
$set1->union($set2)->union($set3);
```

Secondly, the result of a `union` is actually a [DateTime::SpanSet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aSpanSet), not a [DateTime::Span](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aSpan).

```
my $spanset = $set1->union($set2)->union($set3);
```

Finally, both ::Span and ::SpanSet provide a method called `duration` which return a [DateTime::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aDuration) object.

```
my $dur = $spanset->duration();
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't return the result as days, and it's impossible to convert what it does return into days. That means you need to iterate over the spans that make up the span set, and sum the size of those.

```
my $days = 0;
my $iter = $spanset->iterator();
while ( my $span = $iter->next ) {
   my $date1 = $span->start;
   my $date2 = $span->end;
   $days += $date2->delta_days($date1)->in_units('days');
}

print("$days\n");  # 153
```

Comment: @Rock, Assumes the spans are "closed". Tweaks needed if you're going to deal with "open" or "semi-open" spans.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ikegami. Although I knew `delta_days`, as Jack pointed out, the Iterator is definitely a big help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to use `DateTime::Span`.  The [`delta_days`](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.74/lib/DateTime.pm#Math_Methods) method of `DateTime` does the trick nicely:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;
my $dt1=DateTime->new(year=>2002,month=>3,day=>11,time_zone=>"local");
my $dt2=DateTime->new(year=>2002,month=>4,day=>11,time_zone=>"local");

print $dt2->delta_days($dt1)->in_units("days") . "\n"; #31
```

Comment: Thank you Jack. I can do it with `delta_days` but it's actually I do need a UNION of the time ranges then find the Number of days within this UNION set. I find `DateTime::Span` works well to find the UNION but I just need to know how to extract the Number of days in it. Thanks!